# C# windows service fileSystemWatcher multiple files at the same time

Tags: windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I created a windows service with file system watcher. It gets the newly added files and do some process. It works fine, but when I try to add more files at the same time, it wont work as expected. Only first file get executed. Any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: How did you establish that the events are lost? Paste relevant portions of your code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the portion of my code. Im uploading excel file to specific directory where file watcher is configured.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //Set the location for the file watcher
            fileSystemWatcherPL.Path = @"C:/Temp";
        }

private void fileSystemWatcherPL_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
//Read the excel file and do some process.
}
```